# Using the return value from SQL as an argument in another Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am using `MySQL` and have the following SQL tables

```
Table1
id | var1 | var2 | var3

Table2
id | var4 | var5
```

I run the Query

`SELECT id, var1 from Table1 where var3 = X`

This will return multiple values.

I then want to

`SELECT var4 from Table2 where id = Y`
for each of the ids that have been returned from the first query.

What is the best way to approach this? Can it be done in 1 statement?

**EDIT:**

To clarify I also need `var1` from `Table1` to be returned as per the first Query above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to accomplish this.

- Using an in (as in Linger's reponse)
- Using exists
- Using a join (as below)

.

```
SELECT a.id, var4, B.Var1
FROM Table2 A
INNER JOIN Table1 B 
  on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE var3 = X
and ID = Y
```

Depending on indexes, volume of data table design/setup.  Anyone one of these three may be "Best"
Exists is generally the fastest, joins solve certain problems if you need additional information.

Read up on Joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thanks xQbert. I have tried this and it almost delivers what I need. I have edited my Question for clarity. I also need the results from the first Query to be returned.

Comment: Perfect Thanks, Accepted. - Slight side note but, when adding additional Joins what does the syntax look like?

Answer (score 0):

How about combining the two queries into one:

```
SELECT var4 
FROM Table2 
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT id 
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE var3 = X
)
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted the 'best way'.

Comment: Thanks Linger, I'm testing it out now. What would you consider better @Strawberry? Thanks

Comment: @Ríomhaire SELECT b.var1,a.var4 FROM table2 a JOIN table1 b ON b.id = a.id WHERE y.var3 = 'x';